# How to push to heroku behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, heroku

I am using git behind a proxy server at my university. While trying to execute

```
git push heroku master
```

I get an error

```
ssh: connect to host proxy.heroku.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I had a similar problem when pushing to git earlier, but that was solved using their smart HTTP. From what I've read so far, it seems to be a network problem. How do I fix this? Is there any way to push to heroku using HTTP? (I'm guessing pushing through SSH is causing this problem and that the port 22 is blocked)

Comment: Why do you use a proxy? Don't tell me there's some country that even bans **git**.

Comment: My university only allows access through their proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku only supports git pushes over SSH (port 22) - it's likely that your university is preventing outbound port 22 access which causes your push to fail.

Comment: This would really make Heroku easier to use if it either supported https push directly, or supported direct push from Github/Bitbucket etc, who both support https push.

Answer (score 3):

[Corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/) is a tool for tunneling SSH through HTTP proxies

> Setting up Corkscrew with SSH/OpenSSH is very simple.  Adding
>   the following line to your ~/.ssh/config file will usually do
>   the trick (replace proxy.example.com and 8080 with correct values):
>
> ```
> ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy.example.com 8080 %h %p
> ```

Follow http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/README

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy

Comment: A more in depth explanation on this would be super awesome