# git push heroku master. Error behid a Proxy

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, proxy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to push to heroku behind a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648559/how-to-push-to-heroku-behind-a-proxy)

I have on my Win7 behind a Proxy the Oracle VM with Ubuntu. I use git. I try to deploy in Heroku, but become Error:

```
$ git push heroku master 
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Connection timed 
out fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

`export http_proxy=http://proxyuser:proxypass@proxy:port` helped for `$ git clone`.
But not for `git push`.

I have tried:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa heroku 
keys:add
```

It did not help.

I can not update `git_config` or `heroku_config` - Permission denied!

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Well done for setting the environment variable. That will work for push and pulling from HTTP remotes, but it won't work for ssh remotes such as Heroku. Would be helpful if Heroku exposed repositories through HTTPS, as GitHub does.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/README

> Corkscrew is a tool for tunneling SSH through HTTP proxies
>
> Setting up Corkscrew with SSH/OpenSSH is very simple.  Adding
>   the following line to your ~/.ssh/config file will usually do
>   the trick (replace proxy.example.com and 8080 with correct values):
>
> ```
> ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy.work.com 80 %h %p ~/.ssh/myauth
> ```
>
> You will need to create a file `myauth` that contains your usename and password
>   in the form of :
>
> ```
> username:password
> ```

Comment: Thanks a Lot!  I found this Artticle too. But I have the ssh_config File readonly, so I can not replace the Proxy-Default.

Comment: Now I have installed the Corkscrew. But unfortunally it did not     help:`Couldn't establish connection to proxy: Network is unreachable
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: could you please help me with - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21600830/ssh-ing-to-remote-server-from-behind-a-proxy